# How to make a connection with local host database through visual studio 2008 using c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a sample database in MySql workbench. I am working on a smart device windows application and i am trying to connect my local host where i have my sample database to the login button i have created on the login form. My coding

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id= ;database= ");
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM login where Username = '" + textBox1.Text+ "' and Password = '" + textBox2.Text + "'", conn);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()== "1")
    {
        MainMenuform ps = new MainMenuform();
        ps.Show();
        this.Hide();
   }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please check Username and Password");
    }
}
```

So, when i try the above coding, its giving me an error "Cannot connect to the specified MySql host you specified". My code seems alright but i am still getting this error. Please help.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks! and never store plain text passwords!

Comment: does your database run on the same machine that the app is?

Comment: I think there's a problem with the connection string... it should be `Server=localhost;Uid=root;database=mydatabase;Pwd=yourpassword`

Comment: I am still having the same problem:"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

Comment: One more thing i am working on a virtual machine but all my data is on virtual machine along with my app